# Issue in 301 Redirect in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5.4

I update the route of my category pages from `/listing/category1` to `/products/category1`

Old Route:

```
Route::get('/listing/{slug}', 'ProductsController@listing');
```

New Route:

```
Route::get('/products/{slug}', 'ProductsController@listing');
```

Now I want to permanently redirect (301) my `Old Routes` to `New Routes`.

There are just 4-5 categories so I have added below code in `.htaccess` file in public folder to redirect all old URL's to New URL's manually with `Redirect 301` script but it didn't work.

```
Redirect 301 /listing/category1 https://www.example.com/products/category1
Redirect 301 /listing/category2 https://www.example.com/products/category2
```

Please note website is having `SSL certificate` so links are starting with `https`.

There might be solution lying somewhere in Stack Overflow or some other website that I unable to found.

I tried adding below code in .htaccess file as well but of no use.

```
RewriteRule listing/category1 /products/category1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^listing/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ products/category1
```

Complete code of .htaccess file is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/?listing/([\w-]+)/?$ /products/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

So Please help me telling **How to permanently redirect Old Routes to New Routes in Laravel 5.4?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work,

```
Route::any('listing/{any?}', function ($any = null) {
    return Redirect::to('/products/'.$any, 301); 
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: There are some static link as well to update. Do you know how to update route for static links?

Comment: by static you mean `.html` links?

Comment: no no, its something from /listing/category1 to /products/newcatname means complete url will change

Comment: in this case we know what old and new url is and that is not matching with any other url so we can't re-write it.

Comment: if you know what the old and new url should be, why not use the same method above but give that full route instead of using parameters?

Comment: can you simply send me code here for that like if I want to redirect from /listing/category1 to /products/newcatname

Comment: `Route::any(' /listing/category1', function ( ) {
    return Redirect::to('/products/newcatname', 301); 
});`